# Is there a faster way to pass strings into methods created by nameof?

Tags: c#, string

I have a method that takes the following parameters:

```
public static void IfNull(object value, string variableName)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot be empty", variableName);
    }
}
```

This method is called by my application several times. Here's an example of how it is called:

```
Throw.IfNull(someObject, nameof(someObject));
```

My question is, is there a faster way to pass the string returned by nameof()? When I do not include the 2nd parameter, I see a bigger performance improvement. I see a .5 second improvement for one of the most important features in the software instead of .3 second improvement if I keep the code the way it is.

Comment: The difference is not from the diffrence of `nameof` it is the speed difference of `new ArgumentNullException("someObject")`  vs `new ArgumentNullException(null)` that you are seeing.

Comment: `nameof(someObject)` as far as I can see is just replaced with "someObject" at compile time. Try that out and tell us the difference. Answering ur question - no, u can't.

Comment: My opinion: I generally don't worry about the performance of exceptions because they're... *exceptions*. When you say "one of the most important features", I'm thinking that you might want to consider refactoring things so that a value of `null` in this case isn't an exception if it happens all the time. Failing that, if `nameof` is expensive to call, consider writing `if (someObject == null) throw...` without the function call to avoid calling `nameof` except when it's needed.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that the exceptions rarely occur. I was asking more about ways I could pass the 2nd string more efficiently in the case where it is actually needed (for the ArgumentNullException).

Comment: I could try using String.Intern for the string generated by nameof().

Answer (score 0):

Value for parameter variableName is being calculated before calling IfNull regardless whether this value will be used or not. If calculation is heavy operation, you can pass a function which will return parameter value only when necessary:

```
public static void IfNull(object value, Func<string> variableName)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot be empty", variableName());
    }
}
```

and call it that way:

```
Throw.IfNull(someObject, () => nameof(someObject));
```